# What is the actual reason why nakedness prevents us from learning/speaking torah

Tags: halacha, torah-study

This may seem like a simple question, But what is the actual reason for why nakedness or seeing someone else naked prevents us from learning and thinking about sacred things.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Motti and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: לא יראה בך ערות דבר

Comment: https://www.etzion.org.il/he/halakha/orach-chaim/prayer-and-blessings/%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95-%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94

Comment: What do you mean by "actual"?